# Completion block prevents AFJSONRequestOperation execution

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm retrieving JSON data using AFNetworking lib, and wanted to add a completion block as follows:

```
-(void)getData{

    NSString *link=@"http://localhost:8080/address/address/address/";

    NSURL *url= [ NSURL URLWithString:link];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        arrayofA=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"a"];
        arrayofB=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"b"];


        [[self techTableView] reloadData];

    } failure:nil];


    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        //-- This block gets invoked periodically as the download progress

        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(totalBytesRead * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // HUD treatment
            });
        });



    }];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Completed:");

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];

    [operation start];

}
```

When I added the completion bloc I no longer have a result, nothing is shown in the screen, and noticed that `AFJSONRequestOperation` bloc is not executed, I printed a log there and it's not shown.
What could be the problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you trying to set 2 different success completion blocks? Presumably one is running and one is not?

Comment: @Wain: I want to check if an array count is equals to 0 or not. But `setDownloadProgressBlock` is just for progress, no?

Comment: The duplications is the use of `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess`

Comment: @Wain: I tried to verify the count of the array in `setDownloadProgressBlock` (after removing the HUD from view), but it's always executed, even that the array count is not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw this code away:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Completed:");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Instead, put your logging into the blocks on the `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` (where you currently have a success block but no failure block, and the success block is being removed by the code that you should remove).

In `setDownloadProgressBlock`, just push to the main thread and update your UI. Don't bother trying to create a delay, that will only lead to apparently random behaviour. Also, don't try to use the result of the download, that should only be done in the `success` block.

Comment: I was doing something wrong and you confirmed my error. Problem is solved now. Thank you very much, you're always here to help :).